# Entity Framework migration within multiple projects

Tags: entity-framework

The solution I am working in has several projects: start up project, data project and multiple others. I need to make migration on the data project to change the database. I can't access the migrations with `add-migration`. In the process I tried both the entity version and `dotnet` command both didn't work. I also tried to enable migrations with dot net version of the command to enable migrations, but it only resulted in migrations blocking access to database.

What is the correct workflow?

Comment: Are you using core?

Comment: whether all the projects in one version or different